# Categorical Syllogism Question: What would be the categorical syllogism conversion for this passage?

Tags: logic

Passage "Some electric vehicles are “clean” vehicles, since all clean vehicles ultimately get their energy from renewable resources, and some electric vehicles do not ultimately get their energy from renewable resources."

Here is my current conversion but is it correct?

"
All clean vehicles are vehicles that get their energy from renewable resources
Some electric vehicles are not vehicles that get their energy from renewable resources
Some electric vehicles are not “clean” vehicles
"

Comment: Your conversation aside, the passage contains multiple fallacies. It establishes that clean vehicles use renewable resources, not that vehicles using renewable resources are clean (Socrates is mortal, all cats are mortal, Socrates is a cat). And in one case it talks about using renewable resources, but in the other case it talks about not using them. So the conclusion doesn't follow from the premises.

Answer (score 0):

The passage looks like an LSAT question (some type of "find the flaw" question) and is logically errant. It breaks down into the following syllogism:

1. All clean vehicles ultimately get their energy from renewable resources
2. Some electric vehicles do not ultimately get their energy from
   renewable resources

Conclusion: Some electric vehicles are “clean” vehicles

The conclusion does not follow on multiple grounds. The second premise states that some electric vehicles do not ultimately get their energy from renewable resources; this does not preclude *all* electric vehicles from not getting their energy from renewable resources, though even if it did, getting energy from renewable resources is a necessary condition (per the first premise) for a vehicle to be considered a clean vehicle, it is not a sufficient condition.